# Need help solving the equation $\cos a-\sqrt{2}\sin a\cos a=0$ in the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

What are the solutions to $\cos a-\sqrt{2}\sin a\cos a=0$? I did not learn how to do this, and thanks! The answer needs to be between $[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. Show how you attempted to solve the problem so that your post won't be downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Isolate $\cos(a)$

$\cos(a){\left(1-\sqrt{2}\sin(a)\right)}=0$

Now we have to solve

$\cos(a)=0$

and

$\sin{a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Can you take it from here.